# How to get a file generated by SWF from URL?

Tags: image, actionscript-3, flash

so I have a SWF file. It can generate Jpeg images. I want to get that images by url (for ex www.my.com/file.swf#image.jpeg) I want to get just clean image (no flash no sign of flash). So as if i was just calling my apache server to give me that image.
So how to do such sing with AS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using some PHP package like [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) or [GD Library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) should do the job.

If for some strange reason you need flash, you could use [swfaddress](http://www.asual.com/swfaddress/) to do 
www.my.com/file.swf#image.jpeg and listen for the swf address event and generate the image.